# lodash takeRightWhile from starting index

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

How do I get the values from an array using lodash's takeRightWhile with a starting index?

The point here is that I want to iterate backward from a specific starting point until a certain argument is fulfilled.

Example of what I want to do:

```
const myArray = [
    {val: 'a', condition: true},
    {val: 'b', condition: false},
    {val: 'c', condition: true},
    {val: 'd', condition: true},
    {val: 'e', condition: true},
    {val: 'f', condition: true},
    {val: 'g', condition: false},
];
const startAt = 5;

const myValues = _.takeRightWhile(myArray, startAt, {return condition === true});
// --> [{val: 'c', condition: true}, {val: 'd', condition: true}, {val: 'e', condition: true}]
```

I have looked at the documentation https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#takeRightWhile and can't really tell if this is possible.

Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash's `_.takeRightWhile()` starts from the end, and stops when a predicate is reached. The methods signature is:

```
_.takeRightWhile(array, [predicate=_.identity])
```

And it doesn't accept an index.

The predication function receives the following parameters - `value`, `index`, `array`. The `index` is the position of the current item in the array.

To achieve your goal use `_.take(startAt + 1)` to chop the array to up to (including) the starting index, and the use `_.takeRightWhile()`:

```js
const myArray = [{"val":"a","condition":true},{"val":"b","condition":false},{"val":"c","condition":true},{"val":"d","condition":true},{"val":"e","condition":true},{"val":"f","condition":true},{"val":"g","condition":false}];

const startAt = 5;

const myValues = _(myArray)
  .take(startAt + 1) // take all elements including startAt
  .takeRightWhile(({ condition }) => condition) // take from the right 'till condition is false
  .value();

console.log(myValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution included my problem of including the current (startsAt) value as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice along with lodash to do that

```js
const myArray = [
    {val: 'a', condition: true},
    {val: 'b', condition: false},
    {val: 'c', condition: true},
    {val: 'd', condition: true},
    {val: 'e', condition: true},
    {val: 'f', condition: true},
    {val: 'g', condition: false},
];
const startAt = 5;

const myValues = _.takeRightWhile(myArray.slice(0, startAt), e => e.condition == true);

console.log(myValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```